# Trying to delete entry in Translation table (active record backend for I18n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I manage to find the object using

```
Translation.where(:id => 1).first.destroy
```

But this results in an error:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "translations" WHERE "translations"."" = $1
```

Comment: Is there a `id` field in the `translations` table, and has it been specified as the primary key?

Comment: There is an id field, but the schema.db file says   create_table "translations", id: false, force: true do |t|
.. I am not able to make a migration for id to be true

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Remove a translation in one language or all translations of one string?

Comment: Either on instant in one language or all translations of one string, somehow there has been created a duplicate entry of one of the keys with translations following...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by writing the SQL myself;

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( 'DELETE from translations where translations.id = 1')
```

If anyone has a nicer solution feel free to post, I still feel that my translations table should have a key (?).